# Get a specific combination from product with given attributes in Prestashop

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop-1.7

I building a custom SQL query for my module to retrieve all combinations of a product with `id_product` and multiple attributes ids, but currently, I only managed to select it with one attribute and no more, I'm really missing something but didn't find it yet.

To get in context here's my query to find all combinations (color & size) of a product and its result:

```
SELECT
    p.id_product,
    pq.quantity,
    pa.price AS price_diff,
    p.price,
    pai.id_image,
    pl.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(agl.id_attribute_group, ':', pal.id_attribute ORDER BY agl.id_attribute_group SEPARATOR ", ") as combination_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(pal.name ORDER BY agl.id_attribute_group SEPARATOR ", ") as combination
FROM ps_product p
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute pa ON (p.id_product = pa.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available pq ON (p.id_product = pq.id_product AND pa.id_product_attribute = pq.id_product_attribute)
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination pac ON (pa.id_product_attribute = pac.id_product_attribute)
LEFT JOIN ps_attribute_lang pal ON (pac.id_attribute = pal.id_attribute)
LEFT JOIN ps_attribute a ON (pal.id_attribute = a.id_attribute) 
LEFT JOIN ps_attribute_group_lang agl ON (a.id_attribute_group = agl.id_attribute_group) 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_image pai on(pa.id_product_attribute = pai.id_product_attribute)
WHERE pl.id_lang = 1
AND pal.id_lang = 1
AND agl.id_lang = 1
AND p.id_product = 3196 -- My product
GROUP BY pac.id_product_attribute
```

The result[image]

Query with a single attribute (size S for this example):

```
......................
......................
AND p.id_product = 3196 -- My product
AND agl.id_attribute_group = 9 -- size
AND pal.id_attribute = 761 -- 'S' size for my case
GROUP BY pac.id_product_attribute
```

[image]

But no success with specifying both size AND color, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `HAVING` clause. To filter on two attributes, the logic would be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY pac.id_product_attribute
HAVING 
    MAX(agl.id_attribute_group = 9 AND pal.id_attribute = 761) = 1
    AND MAX(agl.id_attribute_group = 2 AND pal.id_attribute = 727) = 1
```

I should warn that your code is not a valid aggregation query. You need more column in the `GROUP BY` clause to fix that flaw. It is hard to tell for sure without seeing your data, but, with a few assumptions on the primary key of each table:

```
GROUP BY 
    p.id_product, 
    pa.id_product_attribute, 
    pac.id_product_attribute,  
    pai.id_image,
    pq.id  -- if that exists?
```

Comment: The having clause worked perfectly for my case and exactly how I wanted. Thank you so much!